# How to create this sidebar menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a sidebar menu like this http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07061TJ, but I can't find the image asset of the current item (a white arrow).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [CSS border triangle trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/):

You can achieve this with a span element in absolute position where you want the arrow and the following class

```
.triangle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid white;
}
```

As a side not: this "feature" is nothing bug an edge case of this http://jsfiddle.net/Xjmp5/

Comment: Is this a bug in the CSS rendering that became a "feature"?

Comment: Do you consider the way the border merge together as a bug or a feature ? What would you do ? http://jsfiddle.net/Xjmp5/ ;=)

Comment: From your sample, I can say it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the arrow is made from 2 div-s

you can see the code ,he set the div width:0,height:0,line-height:0,font-size:0 to make sure the  have no width and height

in this case ,if you set the border into 4 different colors ,you will see 4 triangles,in the shape of a square[image]

what to do next is to set the border-left,border-top,border-bottom transparent .then you get a triangle,

the last thing you want to do is make another white triangle and cover it on the first one ,then you will get the arrow
[image]